# Is using map-reduce necessary

Tags: mapreduce, cloud, elastic-map-reduce

when doing a cloud computing project is it necessary to use amazon s3 as defined in:{http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-cloud_apache/#figure2} in figure 1,
or I can just use a map-reduce and a database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is just one of the many storage options in the world. It is not mandatory for any cloud application, just sometimes highly practical.

Comment: Can I don't use anything which is like S3?

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand what the deeper reasoning behind your question or this comment is. Try to provide more background information, and ask someone to help you with wording it in proper English if you find that hard yourself as I suspect.